# Highcharts HeatMap cell color disappears when hover in Internet Explorer

Tags: highcharts, internet-explorer-9, heatmap

I have created Heat map using Highcharts.
Its working fine in Chrome.
But cell color disappears when mouseover the chart in Internet Explorer browser.

Below is the javascript code for creating heat map.
I have created these properties into options object and then it can be passed as parameter for creating chart to  Highcharts.Chart(options).

```
  var options = {
                                    chart: {
                                        renderTo: 'dashletPreview',
                                        type: 'heatmap',
                                        //marginTop: 40,
                                        //marginBottom: 80,
                                        inverted: false
                                        //width: width

                                    },

                                    title: {
                                        text: ''
                                    },

                                    xAxis: {
                                        categories: ['Sundary', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
                                        labels: {
                                            rotation: 0,
                                            style: {
                                                whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                                                overflow: 'justify'
                                            }
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                            text: localStorage.getItem("XAxis_Title_Text")
                                        }
                                    },

                                    yAxis: {
                                        categories:['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23'],

                                        title: {
                                            text: localStorage.getItem("YAxis_Title_Text")
                                        },
                                        labels: {
                                            format: '{value}'
                                        },
                                        minPadding: 0,
                                        maxPadding: 0,
                                        startOnTick: false,
                                        endOnTick: false


                                    },
                                    colorAxis: {
                                        stops: [
                                                 [0, '#3060cf'],
                                                 [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
                                                 [0.9, '#c4463a'],
                                                 [1, '#c4463a']
                                        ],
                                        min: minSeriesVal,
                                        max: maxSeriesVal,
                                        startOnTick: false,
                                        endOnTick: false

                                    },
                                    legend: {
                                        title: {
                                            text: Measure
                                        },
                                        align: 'right',
                                        layout: 'vertical',
                                        //margin: 0,
                                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                                        y: -20,
                                        x: -50,
                                        //symbolHeight: height - 340
                                    },
                                    exporting: {
                                        enabled: false,
                                        scale: 2
                                    },
                                    tooltip: {
                                        formatter: function () {

                                            //if (this.point.value != 0) {
                                            if (formattedValue[0].toString().indexOf('%') > -1)
                                                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + ', ' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b><br>' + Measure + ':<b>' +
                                                    this.point.value + formattedValue[0].toString();
                                            else
                                                return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + ', ' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b><br>' + Measure + ':<b>' +
                                                    formattedValue[0].toString() + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.value, 2);
                                            //}

                                        },
                                        borderRadius: 0,
                                        borderWidth: 1,
                                        backgroundColor: ''

                                    },
                                    series: [{
                                        name: '',
                                        borderWidth: 0,
                                        //colsize: 24 * 36e5,
                                        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
                                        //data: y,
                                        dataLabels: {
                                            enabled: false,
                                            color: 'black',
                                            style: {
                                                textShadow: 'none',
                                                HcTextStroke: null
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }]
                                };
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: Please, share some code or provide some demo (like jsFiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the latest version of highcharts library files fixed this issue.

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/heatmap.js">
```